# Escaping character string

Tags: javascript

I need to modify `var absolute` to use var `y` instead of a static value xxxxxx.

I have problem with js escpainig.

```
        var y = 'http://www.mysite.com';
var resp = '<div><img src="smiley1.gif"></div><div><img src="smiley2.gif"></div><div><img src="smiley3.gif"></div>';               
        var re = /src=\"/gi;
        var absolute = "src=\"xxxxxx\/"; // replace xxxxxx with value from variable y
        resp = resp.replace(re, absolute);
```

trying

var absolute = "src=\"+ y +/";

does not work.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: you're missing a double quote before the last slash. Using syntax highlighting would have show these

Comment: do you mean "src=\"+ y +/""; ?? it does not work

Comment: I mean `"src=\"+ y +"/";`

Answer (score 1):

fixed in this way

```
'src=\"' + y + '\/';
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need the (back)slash for. Use simple quote instead:

```
var absolute = 'src="'+ y +'"';
```